# Error when run Jitsi for android source

Tags: java, android, eclipse, jitsi

I've got this error when I run Jitsi for android source. I got the source from [here](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Android_Free_Code/Chat_XMPP/Download_Free_code_jitsi_android.htm)

The error was

```
10-17 22:21:07.150: E/AndroidRuntime(14134): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-17 22:21:07.150: E/AndroidRuntime(14134): Process: org.jitsi, PID: 14134
10-17 22:21:07.150: E/AndroidRuntime(14134): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net.java.sip.communicator.util.Logger
10-17 22:21:07.150: E/AndroidRuntime(14134):    at org.jitsi.android.JitsiApplication.<clinit>(JitsiApplication.java:42)
10-17 22:21:07.150: E/AndroidRuntime(14134):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
10-17 22:21:07.150: E/AndroidRuntime(14134):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1208)
10-17 22:21:07.150: E/AndroidRuntime(14134):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:990)
10-17 22:21:07.150: E/AndroidRuntime(14134):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newApplication(Instrumentation.java:975)
10-17 22:21:07.150: E/AndroidRuntime(14134):    at android.app.LoadedApk.makeApplication(LoadedApk.java:511)
10-17 22:21:07.150: E/AndroidRuntime(14134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4564)
10-17 22:21:07.150: E/AndroidRuntime(14134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:139)
10-17 22:21:07.150: E/AndroidRuntime(14134):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1353)
10-17 22:21:07.150: E/AndroidRuntime(14134):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
10-17 22:21:07.150: E/AndroidRuntime(14134):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
10-17 22:21:07.150: E/AndroidRuntime(14134):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5268)
10-17 22:21:07.150: E/AndroidRuntime(14134):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-17 22:21:07.150: E/AndroidRuntime(14134):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
10-17 22:21:07.150: E/AndroidRuntime(14134):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
10-17 22:21:07.150: E/AndroidRuntime(14134):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
10-17 22:21:07.150: E/AndroidRuntime(14134):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Is there something I missed?

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError error occurs when class is available at compile time but not run time and i had solved this problem on jitsi desktop application. May my solution work for you. 
I think you forgot to include **org.apache.log4j** in manifest file of your application.